# Hidden tab bar sticks out in React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I'm set navigation options: `tabBarVisible: false`. like

```
export const AccountScreenNavigation = ({route, navigation}) => {
  try {
    let tabBarVisible = true;
    if (getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) === 'LogInScreen') {
      **tabBarVisible = false;**
    }
    navigation.setOptions({
      **tabBarVisible: tabBarVisible,**
    });
  } catch {
    console.log('route state is undefined');
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator headerMode={'None'}>
      <Stack.Screen name={'AccountsScreen'} component={AccountScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'CreateAccount'} component={CreateAccount} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'LogInScreen'} component={LogInScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

It's work but part of tab bar stick out.

When I'm delete

```
position: 'absolute',
bottom: 17,
```

from styles, tab bar hides normally.

problem shows here: https://pasteboard.co/KaS9WWA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fix the problem. Just add

```
safeAreaInsets: {
      bottom: 30,
},
```

in **tabBarOptions**